# How to map single entity with two different node in requestbody in springboot

Tags: java

I am using springboot app and I want to map request body User having fields billingAddress and shippingAddress. I have define single Address class given below. Request body is given below. How would I define mapper so that request body can be easily transform? I don't want to define separate billingAddress and shippingAddress class.

Json Request:

```
{
  "data": {
    "billing_information": {
      "billing_first_name": "John",
      "billing_last_name": "Doe",
      "billing_address_line1": "1295 Charleston Road",
      "billing_address_line2": "Apt 1",
      "billing_city": "Mountain View",
      "billing_province": "CA",
      "billing_postal_code": "94043",
      "billing_country": "US"
    },
    "shipping_information": {
      "shipping_first_name": "John",
      "shipping_last_name": "Doe",
      "shipping_address_line1": "1295 Charleston Road",
      "shipping_address_line2": "Apt 1",
      "shipping_city": "Mountain View",
      "shipping_province": "CA",
      "shipping_country": "US",
      "shipping_postal_code": "94043"
    }
  }
}
```

Address.java :

```
public class Address {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String addressLne1;
    private String addressLne2;
    private String city;
    private String province;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
}
```

User.java :

```
public class User {
    private Address billingAddress;
    private Address shippingAddress;
}
```

Controller.java :

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @PostMapping("/user")
    public String user(@RequestBody User request) {

        return "success";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace error etc?

Comment: I will get error I do not define custom mapper to inform framework. Right now it won't work because field name in request are completely different. I want to understand is there a way to avoid defining two separate address class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the root node of a JSON has a property 'data', you can map using `@JsonTypeName`, other alternative is to create a wrapper class and map it using `@JsonProperty` to a mapper field

Then you can map the billing address and shipping address using `@JsonProperty` annotation

```
@JsonTypeName("data")
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
class User {

    @JsonProperty("billing_information")
    private Address billingAddress;

    @JsonProperty("shipping_information")
    private Address shippingAddress;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

And finally, as `Address` model fields need to be mapped to 2 different JSON properties, we can use `@JsonAlias` to set an alias.

```
class Address {

    @JsonProperty("billing_first_name")
    @JsonAlias({"shipping_first_name"})
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("billing_last_name")
    @JsonAlias({"shipping_last_name"})
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("billing_address_line1")
    @JsonAlias({"shipping_address_line1"})
    private String addressLne1;

    ...

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks Govi. your suggestion is helpful. Just want to add instead of defining both the annotation @JsonProperty and @JsonAlias, I just used @JsonAlias and it also work .   `  @JsonAlias({"billing_address_line1","shipping_address_line1"})
    private String addressLine1; `

Comment: yes `@JsonAlias` would work as well. But for readability, I have kept both.

Comment: Btw  I was trying by defining two serialiser BillingAddressSerializer and ShippingAddressSerializer but I stuck at step where I have to map these with the Address. That time error says it is expecting one objectMapper but two are found. Do you know about any other alternative method of doing this thing?

Comment: Also I want to know how it could work for deserialization?